# multiplayer (servers) with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, multiplayer

I'm looking for the simplest way to create AS3 multiplayer game. I've made few as3 games, so I basically know the language and its limits.
I've never been into server-like coding.

I want to create a simple game, just like my previous ones, but this time with multiplayer connections. I don't want p2p connection, more likely I'm looking for server/room hosting.

About the game: Something similiar to hybrid of casual mugen game and a 2d-platform shooters (watch TeeWorlds, Soldat). I don't need large database, eventually I could use some xml saved files for that purpose (no need to keep real-time data management). In the first throw I don't need accounts for that game, more like open access, same for everyone.

What are your suggestions? Which engine/enviroment/modules could I use to bring AS3 to multiplayer game? And any tutorials how to start?

Answer (score 1):

Most ready made servers for multiplayer games are commercial and you'll eventually have to pay a monthly fee or so. For now, you could try AppWarp that has some tutorials here http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/basic-concepts/

Others options you can explore are [SmartFoxServer](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/) or [Yahoo Games Network](https://gamesnet.yahoo.com/) (former Player.IO). But all these options have costs. But if the game is simple enough you might be better suited with a Java server written from scratch, or PHP.